# htaccess - pretty url with multiple variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
<a href="sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything">sky</a>
```

`something, 9, anything` are variables
in address bar I want to see this:
`...host/something/9/anything`
so - without `sky.php` at all

reverse rule - from pretty to ugly - is solved - but if you have any notice - pls do:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /sky.php?c=$1&id=$2&s=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for adding your efforts, so it means you are hitting url like `http://localhost:80/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` in your browser correct?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - hmm... I have this site on localhost, but `.htaccess` file is only on remote server, so all rules should be valid for `example.com/sky.php...`

Comment: Ok, could you please confirm you want to hit url like: `http://localhost:80/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` which should be changed in browser to `http://localhost:80/something/9/anything` but still should be served by `http://localhost:80/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` in backend? Am I right here, kindly confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - excuse me if I'm not clear. Pls forget localhost. `.htaccess` is only on remote server. All other in your code is right, just replace `localhost:80` with `example.com`

Comment: Hello vegas, I have replied to this in an answer, you could comment in answer's comment section to discuss more on it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. This considers that you want to hit URL like: `http://localhost:80/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` in browser which should be redirected to `http://localhost:80/something/9/anything` here.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##This rule handles to change from non-friendly URL to friendly URL in browser.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:[^.]*)\.php\?c=([^&]*)&id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

##This rule internally rewrites friendly url to non-friendly url.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ sky.php?c=$1&id=$2&s=$3  [L]
```

Comment: something is wrong. resulting address bar is `example.com/sky/something/9`

Comment: @vegas, could you please do let me know what sample url you are hitting here? As I mentioned above solution will redirect from `http://localhost:80/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` in browser  to `http://localhost:80/something/9/anything`

Comment: this is start - `example.com/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything` after rule it should be - `example.com/something/9/anything`

Comment: @vegas, yes that's right when I tested these in my localhost they work fine for me same as you told in your comment now.

Comment: if you tested the code - problem is probably something unkonwn on my side. So, anyway - thanks a lot, I'll see what could be the reason.

Comment: @vegas, When I test this with curl in linux box it working perfectly(edited rules), see this `curl -IL "http://localhost/sky.php?c=something&id=9&s=anything"` it redirects to `Location: http://localhost/something/9/anything` which looks fine.

Comment: result is again - `example.com/sky/something/9` and error 404 - not found. Cache is cleared. Maybe the reason is - my server is litespeed, not apache

Comment: @vegas, oh ok 404, means rules are fine, its not able to find file, lets work on it :) So in which folder/directory you have kept htaccess file? And which folder your sky.php is present?

Comment: @vegas, basically place your htaccess file in folder where you have sky.php file besides it then try once more.

Comment: `.htaccess` and `sky.php` are inside `public_html`. Can't understand how rules can be fine if resulting string in address bar is wrong

Comment: @vegas, actually what we are doing here is, first doing redirect(to change url in address bar) and then in backend again rewrite to same .php file which was hit in very first time. Something like `non-friendly url------(redirect)----> friendly url-----(rewrite in backend)----> non-friendly url`.

Comment: @vegas, I believe with new Rules(after my edit) URL should come as `http://localhost/something/9/anything` in address bar after redirection from your actual URL, I double checked in my localhost and yes its working fine, if you have linux system you could check it with curl command then.

Comment: something new - I deleted an old file named `_htaccess_old` and now the url string is ok, but still having err 404

Comment: @vegas, ok cool, we are getting near by I believe :) how about changing my htaccess file's last line to `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  /sky.php?c=$1&id=$2&s=$3  [L]` once and try? Make sure you clear cache OR do same procedure by which you can see new URL :) Let me know how it goes.

Comment: in short - solved. There was a trivial typo Really Thanks for your Time and Efforts

Comment: @vegas, oh cool(Good to know; your welcome), What was the issue?(if you could briefly explain it) so my current Rules are working or you made any changes to it? Why because I could edit my answer then it may help future users :) cheers

Comment: your code is 100% correct, I made a mistake renaming the file, sorry

Comment: @vegas, hey no issues, cheers and keep posting Good, informative question and answers on this great site, cheers.